# What is the most efficient way to search for faces in all 4 orientations of a video with OpenCV using a GPU?

Tags: opencv, gpu, face-detection

I am new to GPU programming and I have started by passing haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml and a video file to this compiled example:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/cascadeclassifier.cpp

It seems to take about 3 seconds to load the video into the GPU and then another 2 seconds to search for faces. This works well but the videos could have been recorded at any orientations so if no faces are found, I rotate the video by 90 degrees and try again. The problem is that this approach takes at least 20 seconds to determine if any faces were found in all 4 orientations and hence the correct orientation of the video.

Is it possible to perform a rotation invariant cascade classifier to determine the orientation of the video? Or is it possible transpose the video in the GPU without having to reload a rotated version? Or is possible to apply a rotated version of cascade classifier? How can I search for faces in all 4 orientations without having to load 4 versions of the video into the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things are possible in the world of computer vision, but few are robust/reliable :). Rotation invariance is not the way to go (since effectively rotation invariance means that rotation-information is somehow dropped).

1. The simplest approach: Image rotation on a GPU is quite fast, so you could try rotating each image after having uploaded it to the device, using gpu::rotate.
2. A faster approach: The typical approach would be to learn four different detectors and apply all of them. Detection scales quite well in the number of detectors with some recent advances.

But I am still not sure of what you want to achieve. If you do not want to find all faces, but rather estimate the orientation of the video (as it sounds from parts of your question), you only need to process a subsample of all frames and infer from those (as head rotations do not tend do be randomly distributed :) )

Comment: My goal of to work out the orientation of the video and return the position of any faces. Searching for faces seems like a good way to do both as I need their positions anyway.

I've modified the example to stop looking for faces once it has found 5 and return their positions as this is enough information for my needs. I will try rotating the images in the GPU to start with as this looks like the easier challenge. Ultimately, having 4 separate cascades has to be the way forward. Do you think it would be possible to search the same video in the GPU with 4 different cascades in parallel?